# API - Handling Nested Resources (Laravel)

Tags: php, rest, laravel

In Laravel (with Fractal Transformers), I'm trying to figure out how to handle nested resources exactly.  Lets say I have these routes:

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
Route::resource('user.activity', 'UserActivityController');
```

So if I wanted to get all users, the uri is `/user`,  And if I want User 5, it's `/user/5`

Now, if I want the Activity for a User, the uri is `user/1/activity`.

Here's where I get a little confused.  In the `UserActivityController`, you might have:

```
public function index($user_id)
{
    $user = $this->user->find($user_id)->activity;
    return $this->respondWithItem($user, $this->transformer);
}
```

So here's what I'm confused about:

1) For each nested resource, do I keep fetching the top parent resource (`User` in this case)?  Lets say `user` has nested resources 3 or 4 levels deep (i.e. `/user/1/activity/5/mentions/6/somethng-else`)?  Does each Resource Controller just need to keep starting from the top and working down?

2) As I'm using Fractal, is has support for `includes` which allows me to load related data as needed by appending certain data to `includes` in the query string.  In fact, it's so flexible that I feel I could use a base (like `User`) and get every other bit of data I need from clever `include` usage.  So, is it preferable to just do this rather than using sub resources and sub resource controllers?

Comment: You cannot use both resources on `user`. This will cause conflict.

Comment: @JilsonThomas my mistake.  updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to fetch the models using the id. Even though it's nested resources, it isn't sharing any data in common. So you'll have to fetch everything in each Controller.

eg:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserActivityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the specified user activity.
     *
     * @param  int  $userId
     * @param  int  $acitivityId
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($userId, $acitivityId)
    {
        //  get the user, and then activity
    }


    /**
     * Show all activities from a user.
     *
     * @param  int  $userId
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($userId)
    {
        //
    }



}
```

Or you can extend the `UserController` and in the `__constructor`, fetch the `$user` model. In this way it will be available in `UserActivityController`

Comment: great, thanks for the info.  I'll consider the inheritance idea as well!

Comment: Why both functions called "show"? Will this code work?